# iOS working with a shared file on a server

Tags: ios, http, file-upload, ftp

this might be a pretty simple question.
I'm not into this, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.
I would just like to ask for your opinions on what might be the best and easiest solution to achieve my goal here.

I'd like to develop a simple shopping list application (for the sole purpose of learning) where two (or more) users are supposed to work on a shared file on a web server (e.g. an XML file).

I considered using FTP but I have concerns about the security.
What do you think?

Comment: There are millions of approaches and solutions, make a search at google. I recommend using ownCloud (owncloud.org) for this if you want to pick a ready to go solution. If you really want to implement something yourself, take a look at the combination of https and webdav. This gives you easy and transparent web access plus sufficient encryption.

Comment: I considered using my own webspace as for storage of the file(s). It seems that both owncloud and also other WebDAV services aren't free...

Comment: ownCloud is a) free software, b) a prefect fit for your own webspace and c) free of charge for private usage.

Comment: Ok, will check that again. Thanks! Post it as answer to receive some rep.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "shared file on a web server"? A file that is supposed to be modified by different users simultaneously or just a file that every user downloads? If its the latter, FTP is overkill and it would bring problems in the long run with bigger audience. The fastest (and secure) way to do this is to encrypt the file and put it on fast web service (like S3) and decrypt it on the phone. If you want to be absolutely sure use public/private key crypto - this way you encrypt the file and ensure that this file can only be decrypted, if it comes from you (e.g. encrypted with your private key).

Comment: I was thinking of an XML file that is supposed to be modified by multiple users. Will look into your suggestion. Thanks! You say: "put it on a fast web service", how exactly would the "putting" work?

Comment: Seeing how you need to modify the file, this won't be your optimal choice.